# How to select a value after a drop down menu is dynamically created in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function

```
function actInfo(fund) {
var acct = $('.account');

    $.ajax({
        url: "account.php",
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {fund: fund}
    }).done(function (response) {
        var len = response.length;

        acct.empty();

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var acctNum = response[i]['ID'];
            var acctName = response[i]['NAME'];

            acct.append("<option value='" + acctNum + "'>" + acctNum + ' -- ' + acctName + "</option>");
        }
        acct.prepend("<option value=''>- Select An Account -</option>").val('');
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
        console.log("actInfo: " + error);
    });
}
```

I call this function in another ajax call because I need to send the function variable that I get from the server. In the same ajax call that I use to call actInfo(fund) I am also trying to select a value. Here is the main ajax call.

```
function getPoInfo(trnum) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "edit.php",
        data: {trnum: trnum},
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (poInfo) {

        $('#fund').val(poInfo[0]['TRANFUND']);
        actInfo(poInfo[0]['TRANFUND']);

        $('#account1').val(poInfo[0]['TRANACCOUNT'].trim());


    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
        console.log("getPoInfo(tran_num): " + error);
    });

}
```

The `actInfo(fund)` function works fine. It builds my dropdown menu. But I don't know how to select a value. I am assuming I am trying to select a value before the dropdown is loading. I don't understand callbacks or promises, and I tried `.bind` and tried to append `.done` and `.load` but I can't get a value selected. How do I do tell when the dropdown menu is finished loading and then select a value?

Comment: You can add loading spinner when start `getPoInfo` and delete after `actInfo` finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `actInfo()` method contains an asynchronous operation (basically the `<select>` element is only built after you have received and parsed the returned JSON response). Therefore, what you want is to:

1. create a new deferred object, i.e. `var deferred = new $.Deferred()`
2. return its immutable promise at the end, i.e. `return deferred.promise()`.

The new deferred object should be resolved (`deferred.resolve()`) or rejected (`deferred.reject()`) based on the outcome of the inner AJAX request.

If we take all these points into account, your code can be easily be refactored as follow (I have added comments where I have added the suggested changes):

```
function actInfo(fund) {
    var acct = $('.account');

    // Create new deferred object
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();

    // Perform AJAX call as usual
    $.ajax({
        // Truncated for brevity
        // ...
    }).done(function (response) {
        var len = response.length;

        acct.empty();

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var acctNum = response[i]['ID'];
            var acctName = response[i]['NAME'];

            acct.append("<option value='" + acctNum + "'>" + acctNum + ' -- ' + acctName + "</option>");
        }
        acct.prepend("<option value=''>- Select An Account -</option>").val('');

        // Now that the DOM has been built, we can resolve the promise and return it!
        deferred.resolve();

    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
        console.log("actInfo: " + error);

        // If we encounter an error, we pass it on!
        deferred.reject(error);
    });

    // Return immutable promise
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Then, in your `getPoInfo()` method, simply check for the resolution of the returned promise from `actInfo()`:

```
function getPoInfo(trnum) {
    $.ajax({
        // Truncated for brevity
        // ...
    }).done(function (poInfo) {

        $('#fund').val(poInfo[0]['TRANFUND']);

        // actInfo returns a promise!
        var actInfoPromise = actInfo(poInfo[0]['TRANFUND']);

        // Wait for the promise to resolve using $.when
        $.when(actInfoPromise)
        .then(function() {
            // If successful, we select the correct <option>
            $('#account1').val(poInfo[0]['TRANACCOUNT'].trim());
        }, function(error) {
            // If failed, we log the error message that has been passed on
            console.log(error);
        });

    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
        console.log("getPoInfo(tran_num): " + error);
    });
}
```

Comment: @moe Glad that it helped :)

Comment: So at first when you suggested to ```return $.ajax``` that would return the whole ajax call? including the ```.done``` and ```.fail``` ?

Comment: Yup, I updated my answer, because there is no guarantee that the DOM will be fully constructed when the AJAX promise fetching the JSON response is resolved. Hence I created a new deferred object, resolve it within the `.done()` callback and return it at the end of the method.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the answer and the explanation.